# Earth Engine coordinates in a map

Tags: google-earth-engine, coordinates, maps

I am beginner and I'm having troubles to do what I want in Earth Engine.
I want to put the coordinates under the map, like this:[image: WHAT I WANT]

I already made the layer, but I don't know how to put the coordinates there. What I already did:[image: WHAT I HAVE]

```
var Afa = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
[[[-47.405, -21.911],
  [-47.271, -21.912],
  [-47.250, -22.017],
  [-47.421, -22.018]]]);
Map.centerObject(Afa,12);
var proj = ee.Projection("EPSG:22523").atScale(4000)
var coords = ee.Image.pixelCoordinates(proj)
              .clip(Afa)
              .convolve(ee.Kernel.gaussian(5, 3));
Map.addLayer(coords.subtract(coords.round()).zeroCrossing().reduce('sum').selfMask(), {},'Coordenadas', false)
```

Any idea?

Comment: why?? I think it's much easier to do it using a GIS software (like QGIS) and visualizing the image on it